# Expo - Eas build crashing

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

This eas build really makes me not use Expo and React native anymore...
I've tried Flutter for building apk before, and process is more clear than this, if I have some issues with my build then why not showing it during build process?

anyway, I'm trying to build Apk using  `eas build -p android --profile preview`
And  in the build process I see no issues, but once I open the app on my device it's crash suddenly.

ease.json

```
{
  "build": {
    "preview": {
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "preview2": {
      "android": {
        "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
      }
    },
    "preview3": {
      "developmentClient": true
    },
    "production": {
      "env": {
        "API_KEY": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "CLIENT_ID": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 2.4.1"
  }
}
```

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "my-appp",
    "slug": "my-appp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "scheme": "com.xxxxxxx.myappp",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "SKAdNetworkItems": [
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "SKAdNetworkIdentifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "permissions": ["android.permission.INTERNET"],
      "package": "com.xxxxxx.myappp",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  },
  
}
```

And this is what i've got from logcat

```
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
E  Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
E  write file /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu0-cpu-ddr-latfloor/min_freq failed.(Invalid argument)
E  write file /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu6-cpu-ddr-latfloor/min_freq failed.(Invalid argument)
E  open /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu-cpu-llcc-bw/bw_hwmon/hist_memory failed(Permission denied)
E  open /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu-cpu-llcc-bw/bw_hwmon/hyst_trigger_count failed(Permission denied)
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  Error getting package info: com.xxxxx.myappp
E  tryGetAnimationPainterInstance error:com.coloros.painteranimationpanel.api.AnimPainterInstance
E   perftest packageName : com.xxxxx.myappp App is allowed to use Hide APIs  
E  Permission Denial: can't access SurfaceFlinger pid=0, uid=10068
E  Unsupported sa config!!!
E  mForceHideDot is true
E  packageSwitch pkg com.xxxxxx.myappp, enter
E  current package is com.xxxxxx.myappp and pid is 13544
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  Average freq 1598728 for 387s.
E  Average freq 1522713 for 387s.
E  readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E  get gpu freq table failed
E  client  not found, skipped
E  readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E  get gpu freq table failed
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E  Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E  Invalid file path for libcolorx-loader.so
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  ThreadHelper: thread_callback() 145: More than one pending updates!!! This should not happen. MeterMgr should avoid this case.
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules

Process: com.xxxxxxx.myappp, PID: 13544
   The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
    at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.kt:129)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLoggerImpl.<init>(AppEventsLoggerImpl.kt:642)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLoggerImpl.<init>(AppEventsLoggerImpl.kt:82)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(AppEventsLogger.kt:118)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.<init>(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger$Companion.newLogger(AppEventsLogger.kt:369)
    at com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger.newLogger(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBAppEventsLoggerModule.initialize(FBAppEventsLoggerModule.java:129)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.doInitialize(ModuleHolder.java:236)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.markInitializable(ModuleHolder.java:100)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceInitialized(NativeModuleRegistry.java:126)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$2.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:452)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:27)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:263)
    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:228)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
                                                                                                    
E  open /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpu-cpu-llcc-bw/bw_hwmon/hyst_trigger_count failed(Permission denied)
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  UXEngine Trigger - Returning null
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  Error getting package info: com.oppo.launcher
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  packageSwitch pkg com.oppo.launcher, enter
E  current package is com.oppo.launcher and pid is 3391
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  Average freq 2288525 for 0s.
E  Average freq 1777454 for 0s.
E  readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E  get gpu freq table failed
E  Reading a NULL string not supported here.
E  client  not found, skipped
E  readFile function exception:/sys/devices/platform/soc/5000000.qcom,kgsl-3d0/kgsl/kgsl-3d0/freq_table_mhz: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
E  get gpu freq table failed
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  mForceHideDot is false
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/io_percent not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 2]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/bw_hwmon/sample_ms not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 8]
E  Perflock resource /sys/class/devfreq/soc:qcom,cpubw/min_freq not supported
E  Failed to apply optimization [6, 0]
E  Invalid ID 0x00000000.
```

Comment: Does eas build -p android --profile preview --local work?

Comment: No, i get this error while trying that command 
```Android builds are supported only on Linux and macOS```

Comment: Not sure why this not working on Windows

Comment: maybe try to delete the android folder first and then run it again.

Comment: I'm using expo, and there is no Android folder

Comment: I'm also using expo but it generates an android folder everytime I build. Building apk does not work on windows here also :-(

Comment: So, should i use macOS ?

Comment: This should work on macOS indeed